# Trouble with SQL query using COUNT

Tags: count

list days appearing in reservation where only red
boats have been reserved using COUNT aggregate function. 
Here is the table

servant table:

```
sname rating
Joe 4
Bob 2
Tim 9
Mike 1
Lewis 5
```

boat table:

```
bname color rating
Ace orange 6
Bethany red 5
Cruiser green 9
WindySea red 8
```

reservation table:

```
sname bname day
Bob  Ace Monday
Bob  Bethany Wednesday
Bob  WindySea Saturday
Tim  Ace Sunday
Tim  Bethany Wednesday
Tim  Cruiser Wednesday
Mike Ace Monday
```

Comment: A description of how to convert NOT EXISTS to COUNT would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.day 
FROM reservation r
JOIN boat b
  ON r.bname = b.bname
GROUP BY r.day 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN b.color <> 'red' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN b.color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0 -- optional
```

Comment: Sean `ELSE NULL` is the default if you didnt included.

Comment: I see, this is a very clean of working this out. I tried other ways but always ran into an extra column that shouldn't have been included. thanks!